# Flurry + PhoneGap 3.1.0 using github.com/jfpsf/flurry-phonegap-plugin

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, flurry

I`m working on a PhoneGap 3.1.0 app for Android. I added Flurry plugin (https://github.com/jfpsf/flurry-phonegap-plugin) and did everything according the instructions.
Session works, but events does not! Here is a more recent fork of jfpsf plugin (see comments) - http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/1311/comment-page-1#comment-4346

I`m using Android, PhoneGap 3.1.0 and JQM. At first I use this:

```
Flurry.startSession(‘BRN**********8PV’);
```

And it works because I see session data in Flurry!
Then I tried to add this:

```
Flurry.logPageView();

2.1 Flurry.logEvent(‘Footer navigation’);
2.2 or Flurry.logEventWithParameters(‘Footer navigation’, {button: “Done”});
2.3 or Flurry.logEventWithParameters(‘Footer navigation’, ‘{button: “Done”}’);
```

But none of them works as I see NO data in Flurry.
The only thing I see is Events log session is:

```
Session Time
Version
Details
12/02/13 13:23:18 +0700
1.3.5 (Android)
1) uncaught
```

Comment: Did you add the a whitelist exception rule for flurry.api.com (not sure if that is the right url but I think it is) in your access origin inside of config.xml? Also flurry takes like 24-48 hours to first show data so its a bit tricky to debug

Comment: As for the whitelist I have this line in the config xml.     <access origin="*" />

Comment: As fot the debugging: Flurry says that in the Events log section you can see events within minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I know why there were no events.
You need to add this to your activity: 

   `@Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();

        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
    }`

Only after onEndSession() your events will be logged.

Comment: Could you write in which file this code should be added?

Comment: You need to add this to your main activity.

Comment: Got the same problem, but after adding this code my build fails with error "cannot find symbol Flurry.onEndSession(this);"
May anyone help?